# ansible register with loop debug print not working

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

i have a simple playbook that is supposed to display my services status. and i want to view the output from the machine to see if the status is active or not. so i used a debug print, like so:

```
- name: name_of_services
  shell: systemctl status {{item}}
  with_items:
   - service1
   - service2
  register: out

- debug: var=item.stdout_lines
  with_items: out.results
```

when i execute this i get a lot of info i don't want plus the item.stdout_lines info that i do want in the end of it.
how is it possible to view the output of my command better?

Comment: Try loop_control.label. See here: https://serverfault.com/questions/757461/ansible-with-items-dont-print-whole-item

Answer (score 4):

For modules, including debug, called in a loop (ie with_items), the value of item at each iteration will be shown.  I don't know of a way to turn this off.  If you want you reduce your output you can try switching to using the msg parameter to the [debug module](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/debug_module.html) which takes a jinja templated string. You could do something like this obviously adjusting the regex to match systemctl output.

```
- name: show values
  debug: msg="{{ item.stdout_lines | replace_regex('^(.*).service.*Active: (.*).$', \\\1 \\\2) }}"
  with_items: out.results
```

If you don't want to use the replace_regex function you can consider writing your own [filter plugin](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/developing_plugins.html#filter-plugins) to format the data the way you like it.

In general ansible playbooks aren't a great place to display status information gathered through register vars, facts, etc.  The playbook output is more geared toward task status.

Comment: β.εηοιτ.βε explains here how to hide the full output with loop_control: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62027036/is-there-a-way-to-hide-stop-some-output-generated-by-debug