# Is there a way to hide/stop some output generated by debug

Tags: ansible

Looking for help to understand why I have the additional output from the debug line below:

```yaml
- name: Check kernel diff
  become: true
  shell: "sdiff {{ item }}/pre-kernel.out {{ item }}/post-kernel.out | grep '|' | awk -F'|' '{print $2}' | xargs"
  register: "kernel"
  with_items: "{{work_dir}}"
- debug: 
    msg: "The system is now running Kernel Version {{ item.stdout }}"
  when: "{{ item.changed == true }}"
  with_items: "{{ kernel.results}}"
```

The output from msg is correct, but how can I stop/hide all the detail that appears before it:

```
TASK [patching : debug] ************************
[WARNING]: conditional statements should not include jinja2 templating delimiters such as {{ }} or {% %}. Found: {{ item.changed == true }}
ok: [test02] => (item={'stderr_lines': [], 'ansible_loop_var': u'item', u'end': u'2020-05-26 16:23:37.068718', u'stderr': u'', u'stdout': u'4.14.35-1902.302.2.el7uek.x86_64', u'changed': True, 'failed': False, u'delta': u'0:00:00.008894', u'cmd': u"sdiff /var/tmp/patching_2020-05-26/pre-kernel.out /var/tmp/patching_2020-05-26/post-kernel.out | grep '|' | awk -F'|' '{print $2}' | xargs", 'item': u'/var/tmp/patching_2020-05-26', u'rc': 0, u'invocation': {u'module_args': {u'warn': True, u'executable': None, u'_uses_shell': True, u'strip_empty_ends': True, u'_raw_params': u"sdiff /var/tmp/patching_2020-05-26/pre-kernel.out /var/tmp/patching_2020-05-26/post-kernel.out | grep '|' | awk -F'|' '{print $2}' | xargs", u'removes': None, u'argv': None, u'creates': None, u'chdir': None, u'stdin_add_newline': True, u'stdin': None}}, 'stdout_lines': [u'4.14.35-1902.302.2.el7uek.x86_64'], u'start': u'2020-05-26 16:23:37.059824'}) => {
    "msg": "The system is now running Kernel Version 4.14.35-1902.302.2.el7uek.x86_64"
}
```

So it looks more like just:

```
TASK [patching : debug] ************************
ok: [test02] => {
    "msg": "The system is now running Kernel Version 4.14.35-1902.302.2.el7uek.x86_64"
}
```

`var_file.yml` for reference:

```yaml
---
work_dir:
  - /var/tmp/patching_{{ansible_date_time.date}}
```

I've been using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29512443/register-variables-in-with-items-loop-in-ansible-playbook) as guidance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### TL;DR;

Based on your exact example, this should be your `debug` task:

```yaml
- debug: 
    msg: "The system is now running Kernel Version {{ item.stdout }}"
  loop: "{{ kernel.results }}"
  when: item.changed
  loop_control:
    label: 'kernel'
```

Which will output

```
TASK [debug] *******************************************************************
ok: [local] => (item=kernel) => {
    "msg": "The system is now running Kernel Version 4.14.35-1902.302.2.el7uek.x86_64"
}
```

---

You can't reduce it totally, as you want but you can indeed make loops less annoyingly verbose by defining a [`label` in the `loop_control` attribute](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_loops.html#limiting-loop-output-with-label).

In this `label` you can select one of the attributes of your dictionary to be displayed when Ansible loops over it rather than the full dictionary.

```yaml
- debug: 
    msg: "The system is now running Kernel Version {{ item.stdout }}"
  loop: 
    - some: foo
      dict: foo
      with: foo
      an: foo
      annoyingly: foo
      long: foo
      list: foo
      of: foo
      attributes: foo
      name: bar
      stdout: bar
  loop_control:
    label: "{{ item.name }}"
```

This will give a recap looking like this

```
TASK [debug] *******************************************************************
ok: [local] => (item=bar) => {
    "msg": "The system is now running Kernel Version bar"
}
```

Versus the cluttered one without `loop_control`:

```
TASK [debug] *******************************************************************
ok: [local] => (item={'some': 'foo', 'dict': 'foo', 'with': 'foo', 'an': 'foo', 'annoyingly': 'foo', 'long': 'foo', 'list': 'foo', 'of': 'foo', 'attributes': 'foo', 'name': 'bar', 'stdout': 'bar'}) => {
    "msg": "The system is now running Kernel Version bar"
}
```

---

Also, in order to fix your warning, you just need to remove the Jinja curly bracers, as `when` always assume you are going to pass a Jinja expression.
And testing that something `== true` is an uneeded extra verbosity too, `when: something-that-evaluates-to-true` is enough.

So you should use

```yaml
when: item.changed
```

or, using the [purposed Ansible tests](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_tests.html#testing-task-results):

```yaml
when: item is changed
```

Instead of your actual

```yaml
when: "{{ item.changed == true }}"
```

PS: since Ansible 2.5 [`loop`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_loops.html#migrating-from-with-x-to-loop) should be preferred to [`with_items`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_loops.html#with-items).

Comment: This looks like exactly what I'm after! However, I'm struggling to workout how to fit it in my initial code - I can't quite seem to get it to pick out the value that's within the stdout field. Where you have ```stdout: bar``` above, I have changed to ```- stdout: "{{ kernel }}" ```

Comment: Hum don't, this is just me faking an array of dict just for the working sample. I'll add your specific example fix in the answer

Comment: There you go, you can have a look at the _"too long, didn't read"_ at the beginning of the edited answer

Comment: Thank you very much for your help and patience - does exactly what I need!! I was close with my efforts, but couldn't quite nail it! :)

Comment: 3 hours of fail & try approach and you finally find this answer. God bless you!

Answer (score 1):

without "loop_control" ansible code

```
    - name: 'Print message if CPU utilization become abnormal'
  debug:
    msg:
       - -------------------------------------------------------
       - CPU Utilization = ( 100 - idle time ) = "{{ item.stdout  }}"% is idle
       - -------------------------------------------------------
  #loop:
  with_items:
    - "{{ incidentcpuworknote_cpu }}"
    - "{{ incidentcpuworknote_cpu1 }}"
    - "{{ incidentcpuworknote_cpu2 }}"
  when: item.stdout| int <= 10
```

Below is the ansible execution result before using the loop_control

```
TASK [Print message if CPU utilization become abnormal] ******************************************************************************************
ok: [ansiblenode] => (item={u'stderr_lines': [], u'cmd': u"mpstat -u 1 3|tail -1| awk '{print $NF}'\n", u'end': u'2021-04-03 03:37:38.417169', u'stdout': u'0.00', u'changed': True, u'failed': False, u'delta': u'0:00:03.259453', u'stderr': u'', u'rc': 0, u'stdout_lines': [u'0.00'], u'start': u'2021-04-03 03:37:35.157716'}) =>
  msg:
  - '-------------------------------------------------------'
  - CPU Utilization = ( 100 - idle time ) = "0.00"% is idle
  - '-------------------------------------------------------
```

with "loop_control" ansible code

**Note:** "loop_control" helped to avoid ansible debug messages while executing the loop

```
- name: 'Print message if CPU utilization become abnormal'
  debug:
    msg:
       - -------------------------------------------------------
       - CPU Utilization = ( 100 - idle time ) = "{{ item.stdout  }}"% is idle
       - -------------------------------------------------------
  #loop:
  with_items:
    - "{{ incidentcpuworknote_cpu }}"
    - "{{ incidentcpuworknote_cpu1 }}"
    - "{{ incidentcpuworknote_cpu2 }}"
  when: item.stdout| int <= 10
  loop_control:
    label: "{{ item.stdout }}"
```

Below is the ansible execution result after using the loop_control

```
TASK [Print message if CPU utilization become abnormal] *****************************************************
ok: [ansiblenode] => (item=0.00) =>
  msg:
  - '-------------------------------------------------------'
  - CPU Utilization = ( 100 - idle time ) = "0.00"% is idle
  - '-------------------------------------------------------'
```

Comment: Thanks for mentioning loop_control: label. Setting that to "" made my loop output show nothing but the OK and msg line!